# Uploading Apps to the Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore

So I messed up pretty hard and forgot my password key store password so I ended up having to make a new application and keystore. But when I tried uploading the new apk file it said I couldn't do that because I already had an application with the same package name. So what I'm wondering is is there any easy fix to this? Can I just change the applicationid in the gradle file?

EDIT: Surprisingly enough just changing the applicationid and resyncing it worked! Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide a unique packageName, which is defined in your **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Comment: So how would I completely change the packageName?

Comment: either the applicationid on the gradle build or on the AndroidManifest.xml 'packageName' property, it depends on how you build the APK.

Answer (score 0):

Your best (and fastest) solution is to use the *Refactor > Rename* option - within Android Studio/Eclipse IDE's - to change your project package structure to something (slightly) different.

By doing this, the IDE should take care of changes to your AndroidManifest.xml file as well.

Good Luck!!!

**On Android Studio:**

[image: Android Studio]
**On Eclipse:**

[image: Eclipse]

Answer (score 0):

you must need to change the main package name of your application which must be unique . unique means with same name no any application is uploaded on playstore then only your issue will get resolve

see your problem is you forgot password of your keystore certificate see why that certificate is uses in android is to update the application every time you need to pass password to that file but unfortunately you forgot it so you have no choice other than changing pakcage name also your application will consider as a new application on playstore your previous application and this current one will be seprate application